# Database Smell - Improve current design with multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am in the process of creating a second version of my technical wiki site and one of the things I want to improve is the database design. The problem (or so I think) is that to display each document, I need to join upwards of 15 tables. I have a bunch of lookup tables that contain descriptive data associated with each wiki entry such as programmer used, cpu, tags, peripherals, PCB layout software, difficulty level, etc.

Here is an example of the layout:

```
    doc
--------------
id   | author_id   |    doc_type_id      .....
1    | 8           |        1
2    | 11          |        3
3    | 13          |        3
```

_

```
    lookup_programmer
--------------
doc_id   | programmer_id     
1        | 1                    
1        | 3                     
2        | 2
```

_

```
     programmer
--------------
programmer_id   | programmer      
1               | USBtinyISP        
2               | PICkit              
3               | .....
```

Since some doc IDs may have multiples entries for a single attribute (such as programmer), I have created the DB to compensate for this. The other 10 attributes have a similiar layout as the 2 `programmer` tables above. To display a single document article, approx 20 tables are joined.

I used the Sphinx Search engine for finding articles with certain characteristics. Essentially Sphinx indexes all of the data (does not store) and returns the wiki doc ID of interest based on the filters presented. If I want to find articles that use a certain programmer and then sort by date, MYSQL has to first join **ALL** documents with the 2 programmer tables, then filter, and finally sort the remaining by insert time. No index can help me ordering the filtered results (takes a LONG time with 150k doc IDs) since it is done in a temporary table. As you can imagine, it gets worse really quickly with the more parameters that need to be filtered.

It is because I have to rely on Sphinx to return - say all wiki entries that use a certain CPU AND programer - that lead me to believe that there is a DB smell with my current setup....

<s>edit: Looks like I have implemented a [Entity–attribute–value model]</s>[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model)

Comment: I don't know anything about Sphinx, but I'd guess the problem lies there and not in your database design. The DB design is normalized -- the opposite of smell -- but normalized databases can still have performance problems. I'd think it would be Sphinx's job to index your database so the pertinent articles could be identified without performing all of those joins.

Comment: You are correct, I have used Sphinx to do just that. I think I may just be seeing the flip side to a normalized database, which is degraded performance.

Comment: So your performance problems involve search, or just fetching a single article? If the latter, I'd suggest caching the documents with [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) or something so you're not going to the db every page load.

Comment: I don't see a question being asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything here that suggests you've implemented EAV. Instead, it looks like you've assigned every row in every table an ID number. That's a guaranteed way to increase the number of joins, and it has *nothing* to do with normalization. (There is no "I've now added an id number" normal form.)

Pick one lookup table. (I'll use "programmer" in my example.) Don't build it like this.

```
create table programmer (
  programmer_id integer primary key,
  programmer varchar(20) not null,
  primary key (programmer_id),
  unique key (programmer)
);
```

Instead, build it like this.

```
create table programmer (
  programmer varchar(20) not null,
  primary key (programmer)
);
```

And in the tables that reference it, consider cascading updates and deletes.

```
create table lookup_programmer (
  doc_id integer not null,
  programmer varchar(20) not null,
  primary key (doc_id, programmer),
  foreign key (doc_id) references doc (id) 
    on delete cascade,
  foreign key (programmer) references programmer (programmer)
    on update cascade on delete cascade
);
```

What have you gained? You keep all the data integrity that foreign key references give you, your rows are more readable, and you've eliminated a join. Build all your "lookup" tables that way, and you eliminate one join per lookup table.  (And unless you have many millions of rows, you're probably not likely to see any degradation in performance.)

Comment: Thanks - I have never used `CASCADE` or `VARCHAR` as a PK before. Are you suggesting that I put `programmer_id` as a column in my `doc` table in order to eliminate the join to `lookup_programmer` table? I think I am missing how you link the doc_id to the programmer used.

Comment: "Are you suggesting that I put programmer_id as a column in my doc table..."  No.

Comment: Well, without my `lookup_programmer` table, there is no way to link the document to the programmer - nvm I saw your edit

Comment: @JustinB You will still have the lookup table, but its PK will be different. Thus is a classic argument for natural PKs (as opposed to of surrogates that seem to be so fanciful these days) - a PK will migrate down FKs and you'll have it right there in the "master" table. As long as you only need the fields migrated through the PK, you won't need to JOIN at all. If you need more than just migrated PK, then that's another matter...

Comment: @Catcall It took me a few minutes, but I finally see what you have done: Eliminated a join by substituting in the programmer name in lieu of the previous foreign ID to `programmer` table. I still have the added benefit of updating a single row in `programmer` table and have the name change being reflected across the `lookup_programmer` via the `on update CASCADE`. Fantastic.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic: I think there are reasons, besides following a fad, for surrogate keys. Often, a developer is not in a position to say that a particular natural key will (a) really be unique in every single case and (b) never ever have to change. Of course, cascading can make you *feel* safe with mutable primary keys, but it won't solve all the potential problems they can bring. (Especially if you don't specify `ENGINE=INNODB` in your table definitions.)

Comment: @grossvogel: There's never been a requirement in either relational theory, in SQL standards, or in SQL development that says primary key values must never ever change. A lot of *Oracle* developers fall into the habit of *thinking* that way, though, because Oracle doesn't support `on update cascade`.

Comment: @grossvogel _"I think there are reasons, besides following a fad"_ Yes there are, did I ever say otherwise? The problem I have with surrogates is that they sometimes get overused, just because somebody declared them "best practice". They have their place, but that's not _every_ place.